# PHP PDO prepared statements syntax problems

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am trying to use prepared statements using PDO in PHP. It seems to work fine until I am try return a name with white spaces.

For Example I can return a name like Apple with no issues but I can not return any results for packard bell, Hewlett Packard, etc.

I've tested on multiple different names and when I hard code in packard bell or Hewlett Packard the query returns the results as expected.

Here is the query with the prepared statement I am using.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM job WHERE client_name = :customer ORDER BY job_date DESC');
$stmt->execute(array(
    'customer' => $customer,
));
```

When I query for names with white spaces I do not receive any errors I am forwarded to the results page as usual. The problem is the results page is empty even though there are rows in the database.
Is there something I have to do with inverted commas or quotations to fix this.

Thank You

Comment: What error do you get when you execute the query? (show the output of `$stmt->errorInfo` after you `execute`)

Comment: Remove "," from "$customer,"

Comment: @railsbox: a single trailing comma after the last item in a PHP array is ignored.

Comment: @psycho: when asking for help with technical matters, include what you expected and what you actually get.

Comment: when I query for names with white spaces I do not receive any errors I am forwarded to the results page as usual. The problem is the results page is empty even though there are rows in the database.

Comment: It seems that either the variable `$customer` or the database field does not contain the value you expect. Can you examine the field and the variable just before you run the query, and test for trailing or leading spaces or truncated text? Do the test the other way round, get the row by id and compare the field with the variable.

Answer (score 3):

While the client_name is '**:customer**', you must execute with an array **':customer' => $customer**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM job WHERE client_name = :customer ORDER BY job_date DESC');
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':customer' => $customer
));
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: With many (all?) DB drivers, the colon in the param key is optional.

Comment: Forgive me if I am not understanding correctly but am I not executing the array while binding the value entered for the customer in the following code. $stmt->execute(array(
    ':customer' => $customer,
));

Comment: Sorry, it should be array( ':customer' => $customer )
"," after $customer should be removed .

Comment: Thank you @Brightshine but that still has the same effect. The query is still returning no results when customer has whitespaces in its name.

Comment: Try enclose it in single quote? WHERE client_name = ':customer' ? You may debug using $stmt->errorInfo .

Comment: Tried that as well. I'm sure it is something simple but I cant seem to spot what it is

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. It had nothing to do with the prepared statement for some reason the values set inside a dropdown option field on the search form is only setting the name of the customer up to the whitespace and not anything after it. I now have to figure out why this is happening.

Thank You